# How to embed an excel-file in a word-document using Microsoft.Interop.Word?

Tags: c#, excel, ms-word, office-interop

I have a problem that I have an Excel-table which I want to insert it into a Word-document, using `Microsoft.Interop.Word`.

I already tried this one:

```
var path = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent?.FullName + @"\Documents\Businessprocess\Excel-Templates\Tabelle_zum_BP.xlsx";
var oIconLabel = "Tabelle zum BP";
var oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
var oIconFileName = oMissing;
var oFileDesignInfo = path;
var oClassType = "Word.Document.8";

_wordDocument.Bookmarks["EPExcelFile"].Range.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject(
        oClassType, oFileDesignInfo, false, true, oIconFileName, oMissing, oIconLabel, oMissing);
```

I got this solution from an other thread on this website. The only problem is that it inserts the Excel-table now like this:

[image: screenshot]

How can I insert the table so that it is shown directly, and not over an icon?
I need a solution where the Excel-table is not linked to the Word-table, so that if I edit the Excel-table afterwards the one in the word should not be affected.

Comment: AFAIK, If you want to insert an Excel table without reference to it, You need to add it like an object ;).

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use the `Range.PasteExcelTable` method to achieve what you need:

```
var path = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent?.FullName + @"\Documents\Businessprocess\Excel-Templates\Tabelle_zum_BP.xlsx";
var excel = (Excel.Application)new Excel.ApplicationClass() { Visible = true };
var template = excel.Workbooks.Add(path);
var worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)template.Worksheets["__SHEET_NAME__"];
var table = (Excel.Range)worksheet.Range["__RANGE__"];

table.Copy();
_wordDocument.Bookmarks["EPExcelFile"].Range.PasteExcelTable(false, true, false);
```

In case you are wondering:

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

Comment: How does the Range.PastExcelTable know what Excel-Table i want to insert ?

Comment: You specify the `table` you want to insert beforehand.

Comment: `var table = (Excel.Range)worksheet.Range["__RANGE__"];`

And what should I insert here for "Range"?
Sorry for asking silly questions, but I still have my struggles ...

Comment: `__RANGE__` is the address of your table like `A1:C3` or a [named range](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64#bmcreate_a_name_by_using_a_selection_of)

Comment: Ahh okay, yeah this works really good, but it inserts the table as a word-table, what if i want to implement it as an excel-table (which can be opened in excel via doubleclick)?

Comment: You can use `Range.PasteExcelTable(true, false, false)`. To open it, you can right-click on the table -> Linked WOrksheet Object -> Open link.